# Tacacs VRF authentication

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, aaa, vrf, tacacs

We just got a new Supervisor7 with os 3.4.1.  I'm trying to configure authentication with tacacs, and I can't understand how to make it work.  This configuration works on our other switches, but it doesn't work on this 4500.

```
aaa new-model
username cisco privilege 15 secret 5 $1$qLGb$VQ7BdaJEpzGFqPeC979Uh1
tacacs-server host 10.4.25.8 key ourKeyIsSecret
aaa authentication login default group tacacs+ local
line vty 0 15
 login authen default
```

We can only login with the fallback password.  The switch is not even trying to contact tacacs.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you able to ping the tacacs+ server?  `show tacacs` should reveal some info as well as `debug tacacs events`.

Comment: `#ping vrf mgmtVrf 10.4.25.8
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.4.25.8, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/2/4 ms`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This configuration works on our other switches, but it doesn't work on this 4500.

You're using the on-board Sup7 FastEthernet port, so this is your problem:

```
aaa authentication login default group tacacs+ local
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[The Sup7 OOB port is in a VRF](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/15.1/XE_330SG/configuration/guide/sw_int.html#wp1138747); therefore, you have to configure [Tacacs+ in a VRF](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_usr_tacacs/configuration/xe-3s/sec-vrf-tacas-svrs.html)

```
aaa new-model
!
no tacacs-server host 10.4.25.8
!
aaa group server tacacs+ TacacsVrf
  server-private 10.4.25.8 key 7 ourKeyIsSecret
  ip vrf forwarding mgmtVrf
  ip tacacs source FastEthernet1
!
aaa authentication login default group TacacsVrf local
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a part of the config I am using on 4506 running 12.2

```
username failsafe secret [local password]
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication attempts login 3
aaa authentication fail-message ^Your fail message here.^
aaa authentication login default group tacacs+ local
aaa authentication enable default group tacacs+ enable
aaa authorization exec default group tacacs+ if-authenticated 
aaa accounting exec default start-stop group tacacs+
! 
!
!
aaa session-id common
tacacs-server host [IP address]
tacacs-server timeout 10
no tacacs-server directed-request
tacacs-server key [key]
```

Nothing on VTY for login. 
Hope it helps.